# How to find a regression line for each year?

Tags: sas

I have a data set:

```
"Country" "Year" "GDP.per.capita" "Infant.Mortality.Rate"
"Argentina" 1950 6252.85859891315 68
"Australia" 1950 10031.1213832996 25.1
"Austria" 1950 5733.09811393918 66
"Belgium" 1950 7990.46583983014 53
"Benin" 1950 1104.46653022144 204.8
"Burkina Faso" 1950 515.707854373329 178.7
"Canada" 1950 10581.265520182 41.2
"Chile" 1950 3713.9960324847 147.7
"Colombia" 1950 2087.94941987793 124
"Denmark" 1950 8996.05428012913 29.1
"Finland" 1950 5845.6263157204 44
"France" 1950 7104.00732497357 47.6
"Ghana" 1950 943.100536353646 150.1
"Greece" 1950 3040.41319387776 35
```

I wrote a script to upload this data from the the internet. and i want to do a regression:
log(Infant_Mortality_Rate) = country log(GDP_per_capita) for each year.

```
FILENAME RegProj URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt" ;
DATA book;
length country $20;
INFILE RegProj firstobs=2 dlm=" " LRECL=131072 dsd truncover;
INPUT Country$ Year GDP_per_capita Infant_Mortality_Rate;
RUN;

PROC reg ;
MODEL log(Infant_Mortality_Rate) = country log(GDP_per_capita);
output out = reg1;
run;
```

my problem is: How i do it for each year and save the estimates in a different table.
In a short code? (there are 62 years in the full data set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC REG has a BY statement, as do most SAS procedures.  That will allow you to perform the regression once per year all in one set.

```
FILENAME RegProj URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt" ;
DATA book;
length country $20;
INFILE RegProj firstobs=2 dlm=" " LRECL=131072 dsd truncover;
INPUT Country$ Year GDP_per_capita Infant_Mortality_Rate;
log_IMR = log(infant_mortality_rate);
log_gdp = log(GDP_per_capita);
RUN;

PROC reg data=book;
by year;
MODEL log_IMR = log_gdp;
output out = reg1;
run;
```

That gives you one dataset, but for most purposes you can work from there just fine, depending on what you're doing after that.  At minimum you could write a macro to set from that 62 datasets, but in most cases one dataset with 62 years is better, using BY processing for any further analyses.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful comment might explain what your particular issue with it is.

Comment: One note, you need to sort your data by the variable (year) prior to using a `by` statement.  Your data looks like it's sorted that way, but if it's not, you would need to do so.

Comment: sas telling:   "WARNING: No variables specified for an SSCP matrix. Execution terminating."

Comment: Data set is already sorted by years. you can see the data here: "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt"

Comment: I would guess you need to specify the dataset properly.  Your code above does not have a `data=`, which means it only executes on the last dataset used - which could be not what you expect.  Try adding `data=book` to the `PROC REG` statement.

Comment: Can you run the script on your computer please? thanks i need it for my project!!

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your reg statements were otherwise valid (I'm not a `PROC REG` expert).  You have underlying problems there.  I think you might need to create new variables holding the log(...) values themselves.

Comment: Also, you're trying to use `country`, which is a character variable, as a predictor.  You probably can't use country at all; even if you did, you'd have to be able to show some sort of relationship between numerical values of country.  How would you graph 'country' on a continuous axis?  Perhaps PROC REG isn't the right place for you here; I'm not a statistician but you might ask one for advice how to handle that.

Comment: I added a valid `PROC REG` call in the above; it is not identical to what you did, however, in particular as it doesn't assume any relationship based on country.

Comment: I remove 'country' and did log before reg as you did and it's work. thanks!!